# CSS Flexbox properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Html file:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card" data-type="html" data-desc="I am HTML">
            <h2>HTML5</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
            .wrapper {
            padding: 0 15px;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .cards {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .card {
            width:180px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: #222;
            color: #fd5c8c;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 3px solid #0088CC;
            box-shadow: 0 0 9px #88bef5;
        }
```

I need to remove the space between the cards and fill that space with some more cards, and I have arranged the cards using Flex properties , But I'm not getting how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are asigning card and cards a width of 50%. That makes them take up 25% of the space. This is because card is a child of cards and because of inheritance the rule applies twice. If you remove .cards from the rule with the width and set it to:

```
.card{
   Width:100%;
```

The space dissapears

Comment: Hey thanks , I just did what you said and the space has been removed, but the flex display view went wrong , can you please fix it , check it out in the updated code.

Comment: You again wrapped the flex items in another class named column that has another width set and other flex properties. I'm not sure you need this column wrapper. If you set column width to 100% and the flex direction to column it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much , it's working perfectly.